# How to Resolve the Redundant "/api/api" Issue in Angular and WebAPI Configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, webapi

I have an Angular application and a WebAPI application.

The Angular application is hosted on a development server (Node.js), while the WebAPI application is served via IIS Express.

On the client side, I've implemented a proxy that redirects requests with the pattern `/api/*` to the WebAPI, which runs on a different port.

Consequently, all of the controllers in the WebAPI are prefixed with `Route("api/[controller]")`.

For production, I utilize the IIS "Default website." Within this, I've set up a Virtual Directory named Foo to accommodate the Angular app. This creates a prefix, but during deployment, I include a baseHref flag to address this.

The resulting URL looks like: `ddhost01.dev.local/foo`.

Furthermore, I've established another Virtual Directory within `Foo`, called `Api`, intended for the server-side operations. I've configured a URL rewrite within the `Foo` directory. This rewrite directs all requests to index.html, except for files/directories or server requests beginning with `/foo/api`.

However, a complication arises because I can only make requests to the server using a URL structure like `ddhost01.dev.local/foo/api/api/mycontroller/action`.

This duplication of `/api/api` stems from the initial `ddhost01.dev.local/foo/api` from IIS, combined with the subsequent `api/mycontroller/action` from the WebAPI.

Is there a solution to rectify this issue or an alternative configuration approach?

Comment: I think you can have the url rewrite to redirect /foo instead of /foo/api and the web api routing should be able to pick up the /api route